# laravel8 checkbox deleting last inserted options on view

Tags: laravel

good morning, I come accross the following problem, i have some checkboxes, they store correctly and appear on the phpmy admin, but the prevous submited forms on the view page only show the last inserted, if someone know how to fix it tell me please

i have this code:
view blade file

```
<td>
    @foreach($item->motivo_deslocacao as $motivo)
        {{$motivo}},
    @endforeach
</td>
<td>
    @foreach($item->servico_afetacao as $servico)
        {{$servico}},
    @endforeach
</td>
```

create.blade file

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="motivo_deslocacao[]" value="motiv">motiv
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="motivo_deslocacao[]" value="motivdois">motivdois
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="servico_afetacao[]" value="serve">serve
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="servico_afetacao[]" value="servedois">servedois
```

model

```
protected $casts = [
        'motivo_deslocacao' => 'array',
        'servico_afetacao' => 'array',
    ];
```

controller

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $motivo_deslocacao = array($request->motivo_deslocacao);
        $servico_afetacao = array($request->servico_afetacao);
        return view('admin.formulario.create', [
            'viaturas' => Viaturas::all(),
            'motivo_deslocacao' => $motivo_deslocacao,
            'servico_afetacao' => $servico_afetacao,
        ]);
    }
public function store(Request $request)
    {
$data->motivo_deslocacao = $request->input('motivo_deslocacao');
        $data->servico_afetacao = $request->input('servico_afetacao');
 $data->save();
}
```

Comment: How do you get the `$item` variable to the blade template?

Comment: <tbody>
                            @foreach ($formulario as $item)